# ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, Evaluating _PRS (20160831/pci_link-176)?

Tags: acpi, parallels, vmdk

Using a .vmdk image of gitlab-ce downloaded from Bitnami application stack. Starting it up in my favorite VM manager Parallels Desktop I get this every time I start the VM. All seems well but ACPI shutdown, I have to log it and shut it down manually.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just spin up an Ubuntu VM yourself and install GitLab CE on it, rather than use this 'already built' image?  It might solve the ACPI problems possibly.

Comment: @ThomasWard convenience